# VSTS - Last Access Date for users all set to current date

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have noticed recently that for some reason all users in our VSTS Project Collection seem to have there last access date updated to the current date? Has anyone else noticed, or experienced this?

We use Last Access Date within a few of our scripts that pull user activity data.

-Edited to add image-
[image: Last Access Date Shows current date]

Comment: Do you mean Last Access in `https://XXX.visualstudio.com/_user`? What's the actual date? There is a user in my VSTS, who last access on 8/9/2017.

Comment: Edit** Yes! that is the area, for today they all show 9/27/2017. We know for a fact that some of the users with that last access date have not logged in today.

Comment: Are others in you VSTS get the same result? What's the result if you check it in other machine? (Just check whether it is the client issue)

Comment: Yes they are, we did check from a different profile (I had a co-worker look) and we noticed the same result. The expectation is that the Last Access Date is only updated when that user logs in correct?

Comment: Click you account Icon=>Usage>Select Browse Data and change date filter, then check the history.

Comment: Using the Usage data, it looks like it will update a user's last access date based on if the individual or a a group they are apart of gets assigned a work item. This leads me to think that the reason everyone's access data is typically set to the same date is because many of these user's may be having work assigned to them, however it is not a accurate representation of whether or not they have logged in.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue, I submit a feedback here: [VSTS last access date of user will be updated once assigning work item to this user](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/124091/vsts-last-access-date-of-user-will-be-updated-once.html), you can vote and follow it